# Export environment variables to JSON in Bash

Tags: json, bash, environment-variables, jq

The environment variables can be printed by using `export` or `printenv` in bash, but how can we convert the output into JSON format and then store them in a variable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JQ does that for you and populates an internal variable called `ENV` with the result, which can be exported to a shell variable like so:

```
var=$(jq -n '$ENV')
```

To remove junk variables like `_`, `SHLVL`, etc. from the list you can use the [`del`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#del(path_expression)) function.

```
var=$(jq -n '$ENV | del(._, .SHLVL)')
```

Comment: @DaniyalBasitKhan Converting arbitrary strings to properly escaped JSON strings is not a trivial task for a shell script.